# How to find Chebyshev nodes

Tags: interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

I want to use Chebyshev interpolation. But I am a little confused for finding Chebyshev nodes. I use the following figure to illustrate my problem. Consider I have a vector of numbers I depicted as a line In "A". In "B", the red points are the chebyshev nodes. How can i choose these points? (I have used the picture to say that I know that Chebyshev try to choose more points at the ends)
[image]

Comment: In my problem, i should have nodes at the ends of my vectors too. is it possible in chebyshev nodes?!

Answer (score 4):

For $n\;$ nodes $x_k\;$ in an interval $[a,b]\;$ other than $[-1,1]\;$ use the formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes:
$$x_k = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) +\frac{1}{2}(b-a) \cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi\right), \quad k=1\dots n$$

Comment: I have used it, but as it seems, choosing nodes starts from the center of the vector, but in my problem i should have nodes at the ends of my vector. is it possible in chebyshev nodes?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the nodes are in descending order. If you need them in ascending order use
$$x_k = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) +\frac{1}{2}(b-a) \cos\left(\frac{2(n-k)-1}{2n}\pi\right), \quad k=1\dots n$$
The interpolation should be independent of the labeling or sequence of the nodes (apart from small rounding errors).

Comment: As i depicted in the figure, can i have the nodes as illustrated? i mean at the beginning and the end of the vector of numbers

Comment: Sorry, I still do not know what you want. I cannot see any vector, not to say a
_beginning_ or _end_? Do you mean, that the end points of the interval should
be interpolation nodes? Then it can be no Chebyshev interpolation, or you have to specifically taylor a somewhat larger interval for a fixed value of n.

Comment: @gammatester should tha be 2(n-k)+1 / 2n * pi ?  (plus 1, not minus one) in your comment above?

Comment: @lamont: Yes, you are right. Thank you. Unfortunately I can not edit the comment.

Comment: You can also use a change of variables to translate the interval $[a,b]$ to $[-1,1]$ and then you can just use the more compact formula to find the Chebyshev nodes

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev nodes are the roots of chebyshev polynomials. Use the definition $$T_n(x) = \cos(n\arccos(x))$$ for the Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: I want to find the nodes. by some equations, i can find the nodes between [-1,1], but how can i transfer these to the range of numbers i have?