# Finding the minimal number of nodes required to integrate $e^{-rt}$ via Chebyshev nodes.

Tags: integration, chebyshev-polynomials

I have a function $e^{-rt}$, defined on some interval $[a,b]$, and I want to integrate this function via Chebyshev nodes to some precision $\delta$. How would I go about finding the number of nodes required to do this?

It's clear to see how to transfer the standard $n$ Chebyshev nodes on $[-1,1]$ to $[a,b]$ via an affine transformation (like in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803915/how-to-find-chebyshev-nodes)), but I'm totally lost on how to figure out how many I need.

Also, any good book recommendations to learn more on this topic would be very helpful. I've been learning this stuff ad-hoc for a programming project I'm working on, and I'd like to learn it properly.

Comment: Not directly applicable but you might look at how Gauss-Kronrod rules are used in practice for error estimation and adapt from there. In any case the number of abscissae likely will vary with $r$..

Comment: @Aruralreader Where can I read about that?

Comment: Might be [worth a read](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00211-010-0309-4).